# MsBuild: Fail the Build when referenced Projects outside of the solution have Code Analaysis warnings

Tags: .net, msbuild, code-analysis, .net-4.8, building

In one of our .net Projects we have a Build/Publish discrepancy. The Build succeeds but the publish fails.

The reason for that:

We have a lot of shared Projects which are just dependencies but are not included in the solution.

MSBuild is smart enough to build them when the others are builded, but it ignores Code Analysis warnings / errors when building the dependencies.

One way to fix this issue would be to include all the shared Projects in all the solutions we use them but if possible we would like to not do that because it increases maintenance work when adding a new Shared project.

Is there a way to tell MSBuild to fail when the referenced projects has a CA warning / error?

Comment: Is `ProjectReference` used for the dependencies? If not, how are the projects set as dependencies? A CA error should fail a build. Can you confirm that errors are 'ignored'? Or is it just the warnings?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.